# How to assign an empty array to form field in react redux?

Tags: arrays, react-redux, form-fields

I tried to assign an empty array to the form field in react redux form.
`change('data',[])` ,but it didn't worked.
other fields assigning are working when I used `change('feild1', 'test data')`.
Can anyone help me? Thank you in advance.

my requirement is to initialize a new field(empty array) to an existing form. similar to this,
*formValues.data = [];*

Comment: I don't have specific context but maybe the fields need to be strings? If you really need an array, try "[]". If you just need empty, use "".

Comment: It'll be helpful to provide more context about what you're trying to accomplish.